# How can I replace static value in array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I replace static value in an array?
i want user's first input to be placed at first index.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] arr = {0,0,0,0,0};

int seat = input.nextInt();

if(seat >=1 || seat <=5)

{

//how can i assign first input to index 0 permanently?

}
```

Comment: Permanently? You can't. All you can do is assign it, and then try not to assign it again. `arr[0] = seat;`.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. Can i ask one more thing? What loop(s) should best suit in a seat reservation program?

Comment: There is no way to answer that without more detail (and the amount of detail you'd need to provide is more than you can provide in a comment).

Comment: I think you meant `&&` in your logical if.  The way you have it written will always result in a `true` statement.  Any number which is `false` with the first condition will be `true` with the second, and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are mutable by definition.
You can always assign a new value to any index `arr[index] = newValue`.
You cannot make arrays read-only.

There are, however, read only lists that don't allow them to be altered after initialization, see for example `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(<list>)`.

I don't know of any default implementation to lock a specific index of a List. For this you probably need your own implementation of the `List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of an array can not be made unchangeable or `final.`You could try checking for the value of `array[0]` every time the array is accessed and ensure that `array[0]` equals what you want it to by assigning it to a `final` variable (constant) each time your array operations are complete.